# Replace "I" to "you"?

Tags: python

Using python, what would be a more reliable and efficient way of taking an input with "I" or "me" in the statement and outputting "you"

Examples

Input:
`I like to take care of myself`
Output: `You like to take care of yourself`

Input: `My car belongs to me` Output: `Your car belongs to you`

Right now I just have a simple function that replaces each word in the output, which is inefficient with all the possible inputs. Thanks in advance

```
def i_to_you(statement):
    statement.lower()
    statement = statement.replace(' me ', 'you ')
    statement = statement.replace('I ', ' you ')
    statement = statement.replace(' myself ', ' yourself ')
    statement = statement.replace(' my ', ' your ')
    return statement
```

Comment: First, if you want this to work enumerate all possible classes of inputs. Then handle all the cases. I would probably use a regex, but given the complexity of the grammar, that would be inherently difficult and unless you rely on an NLP library that offers this exact functionality, it would be difficult to do it elegantly.

Comment: One thing to do would be to either search for word boundaries (using `\b` in regex) or split the sentence into words first; and to have a map (perhaps a dict) of the words to be replaced, so it can be done in a loop

Comment: Please specify the question

Comment: @SatyamskillzIN - This seems to be (a component of) an Eliza bot; I found the question quite clear, if perhaps better suited for the codereview sister site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing to do would be to either search for word boundaries (using `\b` in regex) or split the sentence into words first; and to have a map (perhaps a dict) of the words to be replaced, so it can be done in a loop

Using the latter approach:

```
sentence = 'I like to take care of myself'
replacement = {
  'me': 'you',
  'i': 'you',
  # etc
}

reply = ' '.join(
  replacement.get(word, word)
  for word in sentence.lower().split()
)
print(reply)
```

Note: the `replacement.get(word, word)` expression means "look up `word` in `replacement`, and if it's not there, use `word`"; the `word` variable is repeated twice because you could specify one thing to be looked up and another thing to be used if it's not there.